# Old short story about aliens posing as highway tire treads on the side of the road?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

It's driving me crazy.  Years ago I read a short story about aliens posing as
highway torn off tire treads seen on the side of all roads during the day.  Then 
at night, they would go on the prowl.

Can anyone identify this story?

I'll be in your debt for saving my sanity.

Comment: I have been searching for this book that you describe for many years now. I read it in the late 80s or early 90s and I seem to recall that the cover had an image of claws tearing through it. Like tiger claws, or some such beast. I also seem to recall that the author was Clive something (Barker? Cussler?) Or maybe Dean Koontz? I distinctly remember the tire treads turning into monsters (animals? aliens?) and attacking people on the side of the road. It was definitely not "Into the Out Of." I read the plot summary of that book and that wasn't it.

Comment: If it's not "Into the Out Of" per the answer below, it might be Mercedes Lackey's "Roadkill" per this answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143714/story-about-a-man-who-thinks-he-sees-a-face-on-a-piece-of-trash-while-driving-to

Answer (score 10):

If memory serves, that was actually a novel, not a short story by [Alan Dean Foster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster) called [*Into The Out Of*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Out_Of). I absolutely loved the imagery there. Great story if you've never read it.

A [reviewer](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2P4NQBCOOU84Q/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1587150476&nodeID=283155&store=books) states that “you'll NEVER look at tire rubber on the side of the road the same again”, so that's probably it.

Comment: GUESS WHAT! I'm the person who literally said that in the review!! "YOU'LL NEVER EVER LOOK AT TIRE TREADS THE SAME!!!" https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3NUBJ94N6DFWE/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00J90BZW4

Comment: I read that back in the 80s and I *still* think of this when I drive.