# Name of predator-disguised-as-trash story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Decades ago I read a short story about a physics researcher who goes out for a walk/jog. He notices a piece of litter (cardboard, maybe?) blowing in the wind. Then he realizes that it's moving AGAINST the wind, that's it probably some sort of predator with specially-evolved camouflage, and that he is in Big Trouble. I can't remember the name of the story; I could have sworn Larry Niven wrote it, but my Googling has turned up nothing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? And was it in a magazine or an anthology book?

Comment: When a correct answer is posted, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: [Oscar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxgWHzMvXOY)?

Answer (score 23):

[Roadkill](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60859) by Mercedes Lackey. Previously identified in: [Story about a man who thinks he sees a face on a piece of trash while driving to work](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143714/story-about-a-man-who-thinks-he-sees-a-face-on-a-piece-of-trash-while-driving-to). It is available to read [on the Baen web site](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/0671578057/0671578057__11.htm).

> If it hadn't been for the combination of the wind gust and the fool in the red IROC, he would never have noticed the strange behavior of that piece of cardboard in the median strip. But because of the gust, he knew which direction the wind was coming from. When the IROC screamed right over the center-line, heading straight toward a piece of flattened box, and the box skittered just barely out of the way as if the wind had picked it up and moved it in time, something went off in his brain.
>
> As he came up even to where the box had been, he saw what the thing had been covering; roadkill, a dead 'possum. At that exact moment he knew what had been wrong with the scene a second before, when the box had moved. Because it had moved against the wind. He cast a startled glance in his rear-view mirror just in time to see the box skitter back, with the wind this time, and stop just covering the dead animal.

I wish I could claim I remembered this due to my encyclopaedic knowledge of SF, but actually I remembered it from the question linked above because I thought it was such a wonderfully creepy idea for a story.

Comment: It's also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Marion_Zimmer_Bradleys_Fantasy_Magazine_09_1990-Summer/mode/2up). How stable is that page on the Baen web site? Is it likely to remain available forever?

Comment: Hmm. How could he recount the story if he was killed?