# Short story about cardboard carrion eater

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this a long time ago - perhaps online in a newsgroup, in the 90s, perhaps in a printed collection.

What I remember is this guy was driving through the desert on a highway. Some roadside trash was blown up onto his windshield, and there was a mouth on the bottom side. Apparently these creatures/aliens/whatevers imitated roadside trash - flattened cardboard box, etc - and would eat the roadkill animals.

Comment: Could it be the same as this (unidentified) story? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19916/old-short-story-about-aliens-posing-as-highway-tire-treads-on-the-side-of-the-ro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be "Roadkill" by Mercedes Lackey. Seems to be about a man driving and seeing a piece of roadside debris eating roadkill. You can read it [here](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/0671578057/0671578057__11.htm).

> It leapt up at the last possible second, landing with a splat, splayed across his windshield. He had a brief, horrifying impression of some kind of face, flattened and distorted, red eyes and huge, beaver-like teeth as long as his hand—

Got the answer from someone looking for the same thing [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143714/story-about-a-man-who-thinks-he-sees-a-face-on-a-piece-of-trash-while-driving-to).

Comment: Yup!  Spent a lot of time reading the various free offerings from Baen, thanks much!